# "An end" or "the end" in titles

Tags: articles, headlinese

I would like to know why the article "an" is used in the title:

> An End, Once and for All
>   <sub>(a song title off a video game soundtrack)</sub>

However, The Beatles have a song called *The End*.

And is there a rule or it depends on the creators?

Comment: Generally speaking, there are no rules when it comes to song and book titles.

Comment: @J.R., I don't understand the topic of articles :) Thank you for your comment-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two phrases mean two different things.

"An End, Once and For All" implies that this is an open-ended ending.

> If this is from the Mass Effect 3 soundtrack as a simple Google search shows, it's probably pretty obvious to you that there were [multiple endings and plot holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Effect_3), ergo, the open-ended-ness of the song title.

"The End" implies nothing and lets us know quite firmly that this is *the* end.

> It was a song that not marked the end of the medley, but also [the last song recorded by the four Beatles collectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_(Beatles_song)), and thus, appropriately enough, the end.

So it's important to note that context means (almost) everything, not only grammar.

Comment: These are two possible interpretations, but by no means the only possible interpretations.

Comment: @J.R. Not even within their original context as cited?

Comment: "The End" is just the name of a song. The Beatles may have put it at the end of their album for poetic effect, but it could well have been the first song they recorded for that album, used as the third song on Side A of that record. (Besides, another whole album – *Let It Be* – came out after Abbey Road, so it's not like this song "quite firmly" marked the end of the Beatles as a music group.) Overall, I think your answer is misleading from a grammatical perspective. Also, "An End, Once and for All" has nice oxymoronic overtones, which perhaps deserved a mention from an English perspective.

Comment: @J.R. ? Did you read the Wikipedia article? Or is my interpretation of the article incorrect? "[It was the last song recorded collectively by all four Beatles, and is the final song of the medley that comprises the majority of side two of the album.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_(Beatles_song))"

Comment: And my answer does not purport to be about grammar; it mentions that these differences, in this case, are more about context than about grammar, don't you think?

Comment: I read that sentence. I think the key word there is "collectively". I'm about certain the Beatles did other recordings after that, though they may have done so by visiting the studio individually. As for your other question, I think the O.P. is looking for general rules that apply to articles, but that's just my interpretation.

Comment: It turns out that "An end" - the end of a relative, one of the possible, 'deviated. And "The end" - the end of an epic scale, end of an era (for example, the collapse of a great group). Correctly?

Comment: @Other - Flesh that out into an answer and there's a good chance I'd upvote it. I think that touches on the crux of the difference.